# Underscore.js _.partial with _ as argument not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using Backbone and Underscore.

According to Underscore.js's documentation for the `_.partial(function, *args)` function:

> You may pass _ in your list of arguments to specify an argument that should not be pre-filled, but left open to supply at call-time.

Does anyone have a working example of this? I am creating the partial call within a view like this:

```
this.filterCollection = _.partial(filterFn, _, searchTerm);
```

Where filterFn looks like:

```
function(license, key) {
    var organization;
    organization = App.organizations.get(license.get('organization_id'));

    if (license.isNew()) {
        return true; // Always include new models in the search.
    } else {
        return (organization && organization.get('name').indexOf(key) !== -1);
    }
}
```

I'm calling it in the view like this:

```
this.filterCollection(model)
```

The filterFn crashes on the line: `organization = App.organizations.get(license.get('organization_id'));` because `license` has no method `get`.

When I inspect `license` in Chrome, it points to:

```
Object function (obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the function returned by `_.partial(filterFn, _, searchTerm)`?

Comment: Sorry, good question. Yes, I call it with a backbone model like this: `filterFn(model)` (context is the same view).

Comment: I've edited my post to make this more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like they just added the option to use `_` as an argument in version 1.6.0. No wonder I couldn't find much documentation on it. :)